# java. eventhandler interface

Tags: java, swing, associations, eventhandler

I have difficulties with two classes: Program class and EventHandler class.

Program class creates two separate windows, one is "Ground" (window with background jpg) and another window has "add" button, which adds a flower to "Ground". "add" button calls method ActionListener which creates an object of class Eventhandler,

```
   public  class Program implements Runnable {

    @Override
    //implements interface
    public void run() {
        example1.Ground g;
        g = new example1.Ground();
    // ground object
        javax.swing.JFrame window = new javax.swing.JFrame("windowwithbutton");
        //window (JFRAME)
        javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        //content (JPANEL)
        javax.swing.JButton ab = new javax.swing.JButton("add");
        ab.addActionListener(new eventHandler());
```

Eventhandler class:

```
public class Eventhandler implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {


@Override

   public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

    example1.Flower flower;
    flower = new example1.Flower();
```

Everything works fine, but I have difficulties with adding piece of code to eventhandler, so when button is pressed - it should create flower on ground created by program class.
How I should set this association between objects?

Thanks :)

Comment: You event handler is going to need a reference to what it needs to add to...consider providing (and implementing) an interface which describes what you button can do (ie add a flow) and pass that to the event handler rather than exposing the frame/ground unnecessarily

Comment: @markspace But how is `EventHandler` suppose to add the flower to ground ;)

Comment: I tried to add code into EventHandler class, but when I'm pressing "add" button - it creates another "Ground" window. As I understood - I should add reference to Ground created by Program class, but is it allowed to do it somehow in EventHandler class?

Comment: Pass A Reference of `Ground` To `EventHandler` ... better still make an interface the `Ground` implements, which describes what other elements can do and make them accept only a reference to that interface

Comment: oh... sorry, I'm novice, so it is slightly complicated for me because my program has a lot of supporting code written not by me.
If I understood you correctly, then my EventHandler class should have a code, which will create flower in "Ground" of "Program" class, right?
Since Eventhandler class already implements interface, I'm not sure how structure of code of reference to object from another class should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to pass some kind of reference of some kind of object to your `EventHandler`, what you don't want to do is give more power to the `EventHandler` then it should have, for example, your add flower event handler should only be capable of doing that and not, for example, setting fire to the world (or removing everything from the component).

The event handler doesn't need to know anything about HOW things happen, only that when it calls some method, it does.

Start by creating a couple of interfaces, for example...

```
public interface Flower {
    // What ever properties you want you flower to have
}

public interface Ground {

    public void add(Flower flower);
    // Other stuff you might like ground to have/do

}
```

These describe the contract to other users of these interfaces, describing what can be done or obtained from them.  This is a very important concept in OO programming.

You then need to provide some kind of implementation for these classes

```
public class AFlower extends ... implements Flower {

}

public class SomeGround extends ... implements Ground {

}
```

These are the physical implementations of these interfaces, you could have any number of implementations of `Flower`, `Rose`, `VenusFlyTrap`, but `Ground` won't care...

Now, in order for your `EventHandler` to be able to actually do anything useful, you will need to pass it an instance of `Ground` to work with, for example...

```
public class Eventhandler implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

    private Ground ground;

    public Eventhandler(Ground ground) {
        this.ground = ground;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        Flower flower = new AFlower();
        ground.add(flow);
    }
```

Then when you create an instance of `EventHandler`, you would pass it an instance of `Ground`, for example...

```
example1.Ground g = new SomeGround();
// ground object
javax.swing.JFrame window = new javax.swing.JFrame("windowwithbutton");
//window (JFRAME)
javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
//content (JPANEL)
javax.swing.JButton ab = new javax.swing.JButton("add");
ab.addActionListener(new EventHandler(g));
```

Comment: Oh, It helped me a lot! But I did it without additional interfaces since I had some supporting code already. Now my "add" button with method "EventHandler" creates flower exactly on Ground of "Program" class.

I very appreciate your help!